# Python inheritance - referring to specific levels

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I'm having trouble with Python (2.7) inheritance. I'm trying to refer from derived classes to parents and back, which is easy enough if you hard-code the classes, but that seems like an ugly approach to me. Is it? Anyway, here we go:

```
class Alpha(object):
    def fie(self):
        pass

class Beta(Alpha):
    def fie(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).fie()

class Gamma(Beta):
    pass

Alpha().fie()
Beta().fie()
Gamma().fie()
```

The last one calls `fie` as defined on `Beta`, but since it's called from `Gamma`, the `super` will refer to `Beta`. As such it'll call itself again and starts an infinite recursion.

Is there a way to reference the class for which the function is initially defined? Or the class highest up the chain (besides `object`)? Or possibly an even better way to accomplish this without hard-coding class names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope - you just have to write it as:

```
class Beta(Alpha):
    def fie(self):
        super(Beta, self).fie()
```

See: http://yergler.net/blog/2011/07/04/super-self/ - and quoted from there (as it explains it better than I could!):

> According to the Python 2.7.2 standard library documentation, super “return[s] a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type.” So in the case of single inheritance, it delegates access to the super class, it does not return an instance of the super class. In the example above, this means that when you instantiate B, the follow happens:

```
enter B.__init__()
call super on B and call __init__ on the proxy object
enter A.__init__()
call super on self.__class__ and call __init__ on the proxy object
```

> The problem is that when we get to step four, self still refers to our instance of B, so calling super points back to A again. In technical terms: Ka-bloom.

And within that article is a link to a blog by Raymond Hettinger (and they're always worth reading): http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

**NB: read the comment where a user suggests using `type(self)` (equiv to your self._*class*_) and why it doesn't work**

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question ^^ The second example is a little confusing to me but I'll read the links you provided.

Comment: @Mark I wouldn't worry about it being confusing - it can be when you're new to it (I've been doing Python 9 years, but I have to think things through twice now and then!) - but Raymond is one of the core devs of Python, and knows what he's talking about and explains it well... Just have a little play with it and all will make sense *eventually* - Good luck!